# how to change domain name?

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework

i have domain name alfared.in.ua/public (zf2),but i want change my domain name to alfared.in.ua?How i do this?
this is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost alfared.in.ua:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:\xampp/htdocs/alfared.in.ua/www/module/Application/view/layout/"
    ServerName alfared.in.ua
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/zf2/public">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to modify your httpd.vhosts.conf to

```
<VirtualHost alfared.in.ua:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/zf2/public"
    ServerName alfared.in.ua
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"

    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/zf2/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

That should do the trick. But i'm a bit confused as you are using two different locations in  one config